# Why did Iain M. Banks use his middle initial for his science fiction writing, but go by 'Iain Banks' in other works?

Tags: the-culture, authors, iain-m-banks

In the published works of Iain Menzies Banks, we may notice that the author chose to display his name slightly differently. The culture series has him as 'Iain M. Banks', but his 'non-genre' fiction is simply published under 'Iain Banks'.

Was this his idea or a publishers suggestion? Could it be an attempt to add gravitas to his name, like Arthur C. Clarke or H. G. Wells -- or J.R.R Tolkien for that matter.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily uncommon for authors who write in multiple different areas. The author Thomas/Tom Holt publishes historical fiction under Thomas, and fantasy under Tom, for example.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Banks himself answered this question in [a 5-minute BBC interview](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/entertainment-arts-20181130):

> I blame my uncles; I put *The Wasp Factory* in, the very first book what I got published and it was "Iain M. Banks" on it, the mainstream novel.  And **we took it out because my editor thought it looked a bit fussy.**  And also because he thought people might get confused with the fictitious bad romantic novelist from the Wodehouse novels Rosie M. Banks.  So out it came, I wasn't bothered  in the least, and then later on, a few months later, I got what I can only describe as avuncular disapproval.  Couple of my uncles came up and said "What you take the 'M' out your name for?  Are you ashamed of the 'M' I guess?  Or what?" For that is how we speak in Fife.
>
> And so **I said I'd put it back in.**  I couldn't put back in sort of gratuitously for the next mainstream novels, so I thought when **we started doing the science fiction I'll put it back in.**  And it actually looks kind of slightly more American somehow.  I was thinking of being "Iain M. Banks the Third" at one point, you know, because it's a kind of trans-Atlantic phenomenon, science fiction so it seems more fitting.  So that's how the 'M' got put back in.

(Emphasis mine, and any transcription errors likewise.)

Comment: Knowing this fact made John Scalzi call me a nerd: https://twitter.com/scalzi/status/878335915260747777

Comment: I think a real-life romance novelist obtained permission from Wodehouse to use "Rosie M. Banks" as a pseudonym. Though that would have been a long time before Iain started publishing his own work!

Comment: Unfortunately the author is dead, but I would really have liked to ask him "who in heck called you Iain *M.* Banks in normal every day life, to the point where family would criticise not having the middle initial?" - most people have middle names, relatively few people use them in everyday situations tho...

Comment: @Moo at least in my (Scottish) family, middle names do get used — often when scolding, but not only. As in, “Iain *Menzies* Banks, what *have* you done this time?” (We’re mostly from Lanarkshire, but spent many years in Fife.)

Comment: He once (jokingly) said that his science fiction publisher insisted on his name including theirs — at the time, Macmillan was branding itself just as “M”.

Comment: I interpreted "this is how we speak in Fife" to mean "we are constantly razzing each other about one thing or another."

Comment: David & @AdamT et al -  Far too minor to be a question in itself, but I'd love to know if he considered himself a 'menziz' or a 'mingus', as the name has two distinct pronunciations [I've known both in my lifetime].

Comment: @Tetsujin - according to Wikipedia it sounds more like "mengis" which probably matches your second suggestion but that could just be Wikipedia providing the more common pronunciation. I don't personally recall any interviews. etc. where he himself pronounced it though.

Comment: @AdamT - Thanks. Give or take how you'd transliterate it from a heavy Scots accent, that would seem to agree. [I guessed the transliteration too, so plenty of room for error.]

Comment: Baffled how the editor could seriously have thought the author of Wasp Factory might be confused by some people with "the fictitious bad romantic novelist from the Wodehouse novels Rosie M. Banks"

Answer (score 13):

According to the Wikipedia article on the author

> Banks published work under two names. His parents had meant to name
> him "Iain Menzies Banks", but his father mistakenly registered him as
> "Iain Banks". Banks still used the middle name and submitted The Wasp
> Factory for publication as "Iain M. Banks". Banks's editor inquired
> about the possibility of omitting the 'M' as it appeared "too fussy"
> and the potential existed for confusion with Rosie M. Banks, a
> romantic novelist in the Jeeves novels by P. G. Wodehouse; Banks
> agreed to the omission. After three mainstream novels, Banks's
> publishers agreed to publish his first science fiction (SF) novel
> Consider Phlebas. To create a distinction between the mainstream and
> the SF, Banks suggested returning the 'M' to his name, which was then
> used in all of his science fiction works.